# check the object is created and create new one if not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to create a object to insert a new data or update the value.I want to check the object is created and then create a new object.before create a object I want to check exit or not

```
$status_tracker=new status_tracker();
```

Comment: do you want to check the `asset_status_tracker` object is created or not??

Comment: yes exactly @ Rimon Kha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you try to achieve but have you tried `firstOrCreate` method from Eloquent? Here is the sample code from documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

```
// Retrieve flight by name, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Comment: I think `updateOrCreate()` would do better (to avoid duplicate) @RafiRamadhan